# Gecko web browser automate drag and drop event

Tags: c#, web, gecko, geckofx

I am trying to fill a web page fields programmatically and I can't make the upload images section as I need to raise drag and drop event then pass each imnage in the event handler. is there anyone have any idea about how I can do that with GeckoFX web browser?

```
foreach(GeckoElement input in inputColz)
{
    try
    {
        string inputName = input.GetAttribute("name");
        if (inputName.Contains("image["))
        {
          //create event for drag and drop or something like that?        
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```